# Individual Unit selection in RTS games

Tags: javascript, mouse, selection

In most RTS games only ONE unit can be active at a time (of course, if you don`t use a selection box over multiple units). So, if you select the second unit, the first one is deselected automatically. How is it possible to achieve in JavaScript?

`

```
function knightMove(){
    console.log("I move");    
}


function riderMove(){
    console.log("I move too");    
}


let knight = document.querySelector(".knight");
let rider = document.querySelector(".rider");


// UNIT SELECTION
function select(unit,funct1){
    unit.addEventListener("click",selectedUnit);
    function selectedUnit(){
    window.addEventListener("keydown",funct1);
    unit.style.boxShadow = "0 0 44px 22px red";
    console.log(name, "IS SELECTED");
    // DESELECT IF BACKGROUND IS CLICKED
    bg.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        window.removeEventListener("keydown",funct1);
        unit.style.boxShadow = "0 0 44px 22px white";
        console.log(name, "IS DESELECTED");
    })
    }
}

select(knight,knightMove);
select(rider,riderMove);
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to store the one selected unit as a global variable.

Then you can simply add and remove a CSS class as necessary

```js
const knight = document.querySelector('.knight');
const rider = document.querySelector('.rider');
let selectedUnit = null;

for (const unit of [knight, rider]) unit.addEventListener('click', selectUnit);
document.addEventListener('click', deselectCurrentUnit);

function deselectCurrentUnit(){
  if (selectedUnit) selectedUnit.classList.remove('selected');
}

function selectUnit(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  deselectCurrentUnit();
  const unit = event.target;
  selectedUnit = unit;
  unit.classList.add('selected');
}
```

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

.unit {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 44px 22px white;
}

.selected {
  box-shadow: 0 0 44px 22px red;
}
```

```html
  <p class="knight unit">Knight</p>
  <p class="rider unit">Rider</p>
```

Comment: Thank you my friend! You saved my n++ sleepless nights!